# Testing aurelia customElement with bindable and dependencies

Tags: unit-testing, aurelia, custom-element, bindable

Im using the 1.0.0-beta.1 of Aurelia and try to write some unit tests.

I have a customElement like this:

```
...
@inject(BindingEngine, Class1, Class2)
export class MyElement{

@bindable data;

constructor (bindingEngine, class1, class2) {
    ...
}
...
```

And i want to create a testable instance of MyElement with Mocks of Class1&Class2
and working bindable-field data.

What i found out - so far - is, that the examples with BehaviorInstance no longer work due to API changes [described here](http://blog.durandal.io/2015/10/13/aurelia-mid-october-2015-releases-performance-and-portable-javascript/).

After looking in the [Tests from aurelia-templating](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/master/test/behavior-testing.js#L25-L35),
my approach now looks some kind like this:

```
import {TemplatingEngine} from 'aurelia-templating';
import {Container} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {BindingEngine} from 'aurelia-binding';

import { Class1Mock, Class2Mock } from './myMocks';

describe('The MyElement customElement', () => {
    let container;
    let bindingEngine;
    let templateEngine;

    let myElement;

    beforeEach(() => {
        container = new Container();

        //Add my mocks to DI container?
        container.registerInstance('Class1', new Class1Mock());
        container.registerInstance('Class2', new Class2Mock());

        templateEngine = container.get(TemplatingEngine);
        bindingEngine  = container.get(BindingEngine);

        myElement = templateEngine.createViewModelForUnitTest(MyElement);
    }

    it('should be initialized', (done) => {

        expect(myElement).not.toBe(null);
        expect(myElement).not.toBe(undefined);
        done();
    });
}
```

It fails already at requesting the bindingEngine from the DI Container or when left out at creating the MyElement-VieModel

```
Error: Error invoking TaskQueue. Check the inner error for details.
    ------------------------------------------------
    inner error: TypeError: _aureliaPal.DOM.createMutationObserver is not a function
        at makeRequestFlushFromMutationObserver (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-task-queue.js:13:36)
        at new TaskQueue (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-task-queue@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-task-queue.js:59:41)
        at Object.invoke (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:334:14)
        at InvocationHandler.invoke (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:309:168)
        at Container.invoke (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:557:25)
        at StrategyResolver.get (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:145:37)
        at Container.get (../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:488:41)
        at Object.invoke (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:354:33)
        at InvocationHandler.invoke (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:309:168)
        at Container.invoke (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:557:25)
        at StrategyResolver.get (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:145:37)
        at Container.get (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:488:41)
        at Object.invoke (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:354:33)
        at InvocationHandler.invoke (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:309:168)
        at Container.invoke (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:557:25)
        at StrategyResolver.get (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:145:37)
        at Container.get (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:488:41)
        at new AggregateError (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-pal@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-pal.js:20:13)
        at Container.invoke (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:559:15)
        at Object.invoke (.../jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:344:33)
```

So, how do i do this thing right ?

------ Edit:

The Answer from Michael Malone works perfect. For anybody, who come to this question, this is how my example works:

```
import {TemplatingEngine} from 'aurelia-templating';
import {Container} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {BindingEngine} from 'aurelia-binding';
import {initialize} from 'aurelia-pal-browser';

import { Class1Mock, Class2Mock } from './myMocks';

describe('The MyElement customElement', () => {
    let container;
    let bindingEngine;
    let templateEngine;

    let myElement;

    initialize();

    beforeEach(() => {
        container = new Container();

        //Add my mocks to DI container?
        container.registerInstance('Class1', new Class1Mock());
        container.registerInstance('Class2', new Class2Mock());

        templateEngine = container.get(TemplatingEngine);
        bindingEngine  = container.get(BindingEngine);

        myElement = templateEngine.createViewModelForUnitTest(MyElement);
    }

    it('should be initialized', (done) => {

        expect(myElement).not.toBe(null);
        expect(myElement).not.toBe(undefined);
        done();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere in your tests, you need to do this:

```
import {initialize} from 'aurelia-pal-browser';

initialize();
```

(as it's executed inline, it just needs to be somewhere in your tests.  We have it in a separate `initialize.spec.js` file)

Comment: Thank you! Finally... =) You are my hero of the day!